# Remove menu item from Show View in a RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application created with Eclipse Oxygen (Release 4.7.0) and I would like to remove from the menu the items that open the standard views, such as History and Synchronize from under Team.

I am trying to clean up the menu and such views are not needed in my application.

Unfortunately I didn't find any way to remove them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

menu.setToBeRendered() method will can be used to manipulate rendering

```
 List<MMenuElement> children = mTrimmedWindow.getMainMenu().getChildren();
 for (MMenuElement child : children) {
 if (child instanceof MMenu) {
     MMenu menu = (MMenu) child;
     if (menuId != null && menuId.equals(menu.getElementId())) {
        menu.setToBeRendered(false);
        menu.setVisible(false);
     }
 }
```